# Canyon Grail CF SL install 33m tires?

Tags: road-bike, gravel

Can I install the 33mm tires on this bike => https://www.canyon.com/en-de/road-bikes/gravel-bikes/grail/grail-cf-sl-7.0/2198.html

I don't like the 40mm tires it currently has? I don't have the bike, this is like a before you buy question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DT Swiss C 1850 Spline wheels on that model of the grail have an inner width of 22mm, which will take a 33mm tire.

There are many rim/tire width charts on the web if you search for them, but here's [the official one for DT Swiss wheels](https://dycteyr72g97f.cloudfront.net/uploads/W0C1800AIDXSA04482/MAN_WXD10000000866S_WEB_ZZ_001.pdf).

Comment: thanks. also do you have any thought on Canyon Grail CF vs Inflite CF bike?

Comment: Product recomendations are off topic here, but the Inflite is specifically a cyclocross machine with less bottom bracket drop. Interestingly the both bikes have the same chainstay length and head tube angle though.